# Hibernate: Retrieve rows that are not joined

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have two tables joined together with entities like this (entities anonymized, and trimmed of irrelevant properties):

Email
 - Email_ID
 - Title
 - Body (hibernate uses a Body_ID field here)

Body
 - Body_ID
 - Body_Text

I'd like to retrieve all Email entries that do not have an associated Body row (ie, Body_ID is null).  What HQL would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an Email object with a @OneToOne or @ManyToOne to Body:

`select e from Email as e where e.body is null`

Comment: This returns 0 results... I assume because there is no e.body at all (since the body row doesn't exist at all).

Answer (score 1):

assuming email can have only one body:

```
from Email e where e.body is null
```